# How is the OrientDB used on famous web services?

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, orientdb

I saw the presentation http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Presentations.
They're talking the product is used on Twitter, Facebook, Amazon, Google.. and etc. What isthe product used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they say NoSQL is used by those companies.  Those companies are not part of the OrientDB customer list.  From what I see OrientDB looks very promising but is new and is done by a small company.